# Draw a trendline with Plotly Line

Tags: plotly-dash, plotly-python

Is it possible to draw a trendline with Plotly line graph?

```
figure = px.line(x=year_week, y=num_accidents,
                 labels=dict(time_from_db="Time", 
                 num_accidents="Num of Accidents"),
                 title="Number of Accidents Per Week", line_shape='spline',
                 trendline="ols")
```

The above code does not work unless I remove trendline="old".

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using `px.scatter` instead of `px.line`;

You just need to update your figure object and change the mode to lines, as:

```
fig.update_traces(mode = 'lines')
```

Full code

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# data
df = px.data.stocks()[['GOOG', 'AAPL']]

# your choices
target = 'GOOG'

# plotly
fig = px.scatter(df, 
                 x=target,
                 y=[c for c in df.columns if c != target],
                 trendline='ols',
                 title="trendline example")
fig.update_traces(mode='lines')
fig.data[-1].line.color='green'
fig
```

I hope it can solve your problem.

Regards,
Leonardo

Comment: My data has date in the format of YYYY-WW, for instance 2022-39, to specify this week number. However Plotly is unable to understand this and gives me an error such as "dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: bad month number 0; must be 1-12: 2019-00   present at position 0" for the year 2019 and week number 00. How do I tell Plotly/Dash about my format?

Comment: Is there a way to specify x-axis to get type:category instead of date? Might be simpler.

Comment: Hey Bruce, you can set your x-axis as category by using `fig.update_xaxes(type='category')` ... Also, I would suggest you read -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers; Regards, Leonardo